# adding "watcher" at the end of a word to coin a new word

Tags: word-request

The word of **birdwatcher** consists of two separate words, i.e. bird and watcher, meaning a person who watches birds in their natural environment and identifies different breeds, as a hobby.

Now I want to know whether it is possible we add watcher at the end of some words, like **animal-watcher**, **nature-watcher**, **flower-watcher**, **sky-watcher**, etc.?

Comment: I think the examples where the two words have become conjoined are far fewer than the words where the first word and 'watcher' are separate. That is, all your suggestions (other than birdwatcher) look strange when they are written as one word. However, they are all possible to say, but written as two separate words.

Comment: @jmb is it possible  that we use them by hyphen, i mean sky-watcher?

Comment: Birdwatcher is a hobbyist, someone who observes birds in their natural habitat, and identifies them. I'm positive that wiktionary will have a list of names with the suffix *watcher*

Comment: I thought there would be more https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/watcher and also here https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/watcher

Comment: You can certainly add **watcher** to as many nouns as you like. If enough people follow your example and dictionaries start recording your usages, they will be recognised. Until then, they may look strange. The use of a hyphen is a halfway step, probably the most sensible route to coining a new word.